# guten appetit oder guten nappetit? Welches ist richtig

Tags: pronunciation

Was ist richtig, guten appetit oder guten nappetit?

Ich höre immer "guten nappetit".
"guten appetit" oder "guten nappetit"? Welches ist richtig

When it's written "guten appetit", why it's pronounced "guten nappetiit"?

I hear "guten nappetit" always, but i always say "guten appetit".
Im i pronouncing it wrong?

Comment: Why would someone introduce an additional "n" before "Appetit"?

Comment: "Appet**ii**t" because long syllable indicated by a single and not double "t" at the end, and also because dictionary.

Comment: why puting it on hold ?? professor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since *Appetit* starts with an *A*, a long pause between *guten* and *Appetit* would be necessary to make it really clear, where *guten* ends and *Appetit* starts.

Noone is doing such a long pause. Because it's obvious what is meant. There is no *Nappetit* as every dictionary will confirm.

Comment: It wouldn't require a "long pause", it would require a glottal stop /ʔ/. That's the sound that Germans pronounce (in formal speech) before every initial vowel and that technically is a consonant, even though Germans don't perceive it as a consonant. In informal speech, the glottal stop is often omitted (/guːtənʔɑːbənt/ -> /gutənɑbənt/), leading to the OP's confusion.

Comment: @Uwe Since the *A* in *Appetit* is short, a glottal stop doesn't make it really clear for someone struggeling with word boundaries.

Comment: Depending of the native language of that person, it may make it *very* clear. There are lots of languages worldwide in which the glottal stop is a proper phoneme.

Comment: @Uwe Or as thew Mainzelmännchen would put it: /gunɑmt/!

Answer (score 3):

What you hear is most likely a very short to no break at all between the two words, so it becomes *Gutenappetit*. The correct pronunciation is, of course as written, with a short but audible break between the two words.

Comment: Das Tippen am Telefon dauert doch entschieden zu lange. ;)

Comment: Faule Ausrede, ich hab auch am Handy getippt :p Wobei fairerweise muss man sagen nicht getippt, sondern geswipet. Vielleicht hilft das ja beim nächsten Mal zur schnelleren Antwort? :D

Comment: OP sagt doch ganz klar, er hört/versteht was anderes, als geschrieben ist. Warum, außer einer versuchten Retourkutsche, Du jetzt hier offtopic siehst, kann ich nicht nachvollziehen.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it correctly.

"guten Appetit" is the only correct form, in writing or speaking.
As people like to play with their language, so thats why the other versions you wrote are spoken. But they are still not correct.

A small link to the the most important dictionary of the german language.
https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Appetit